# Kernel panic on shutdown/restart when relay board connected

Tags: hardware, raspbian-stretch, kernel

I have a 3B+ with an added [relay board](https://www.waveshare.com/img/devkit/accBoard/RPi-Relay-Board/RPi-Relay-Board-intro.jpg).

It's running Rasbian Stretch Lite (Linux blinky-stockholm 4.14.69-v7+ #1141 SMP Mon Sep 10 15:26:29 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux)

It seems like, if the relay-board isn't "activated" the pi can shutdown/restart without issue. But if any of the relays have been activated, the s/r fails.

Here's what it can look like (it can look slightly different from time to time).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvRow.jpg

Where do I start?

Comment: There were some problems like this with recent kernels. Start with update / upgrade to get a newer version. IIRC a `sudo rpi-update` may also be necessary in this case

Comment: Updated everything ~2 weeks ago and after that the issue still persisted, but I'll give it another go! Thanks @Dirk.

Comment: There have been several updates recently, including some for shutdown/reboot problems. Package repo is at 4.14.70 and github repo at 4.14.73

Comment: Coolio, thanks. I should've checked that myself. Will report back with results!

Comment: You were 100% correct @Dirk. This solved it. Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some problems like this with recent kernels. 
A solution was committed in v4.14.70, but I think they were only released in v.14.71.

Current package repo (update/upgrade) is at v4.14.70 and current github repo is at v4.14.73. Try update/upgrade first to see if it solves the problem. If that does not work then you can use `sudo rpi-update`